# Add a class to body

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I add a class to the body in ES6 JS?

I've tried:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body.classList.add('my-class');
```

It fails. No Jquery please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')`. `getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. They don’t have `classList`s. The console should’ve told you already.

Comment: fix: `body[0].classList`

Comment: also a minor thing, if you don't intend to change the variable value, consider using `const` instead of `let`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem for your code is document.getElementsByTagName('body') will return a HTMLCollection, you need to

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

there is an example https://plnkr.co/edit/MFTB95gzYZOYKIJvc5DK?p=preview